# 'Telerik.Web.UI' or one of its dependencies unable to load; .net framework version 4.5 Telerik.Web.UI version: 2015, 1, 401, 45

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, telerik, runtime-error

The application was working just fine until last week, however, the application gives this error. What could have possibly gone wrong?

> 'Telerik.Web.UI' or one of its dependencies unable to load; .net framework version 4.5 Telerik.Web.UI version: 2015, 1, 401, 45

How to handle the error?

[image]